# Copy constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have these classes:

first:

```
 class C 
 {
     public:
     C(const C& c):_s(c._s){}
     c():_s(""){}

     string _s;
 }
```

second:

```
class C2: public C
{
    public:
    C2(const C2 & c2):_i(c2.i){}
    C2():_i(0){}

    int _i;
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    C2 c2;
    C2._s="hello";
    c2._i=42;
    C2 c3(c2);
    cout<<c3._s<<" "<<c3._i<<endl;
}
```

and the output is 42. My question is, why is the output 42? A base constructor is always called before the derived constructors, so this line:

```
C2 c3(c2);
```

should call `C`'s copy constructor and should copy "hello", meaning the output should be hello. What am I missing out here?

Comment: Your code is wrong - you mix up your cases and your underscores are wrong as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is

```
C2(const C2 & c2):_i(c2.i){}
```

doesn't initialize `_s` to the values stored in `c2` because the default (parameterless) constructor of base class is called unless specified otherwise and so `_s` is also initialized with its default constructor, not copy constructor.

Specifically in your case `C2::(const C2&)` invokes `C::C()` and that invokes `string::string()`.

You have to explicitly call the right base constructor:

```
C2(const C2 & c2) :
  C( c2 ),
  _i(c2.i)
{
}
```

Comment: You should initialise the base before the derive members.

Comment: @Ed Heal: I fixed that, but are you aware that it doesn't affect behavior?

Comment: It can do. It has been known that static member functions that reply on the base class are used in initialisation lists to initialise derived members.

Comment: q: if OP'd omitted C2's copy constructor altogether it would have done a shallow copy and worked?

Comment: @queBurro: Yes, it would - the compiler-generated constructor would call the base copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the typo (string s->string _s), the copy constructor of the derived class should call the constructor for the base class

i.e.

```
C2(const C2 & c2):C(c2), _i(c2.i){}
```

BTW - The question would be easier with less similar names for types as variables

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor for the object is called.  The default (compiler
generated) copy constructor calls the copy constructor for each member,
then the copy constructor for each base class.  A copy constructor
written by you does exactly what you wrote, no more, no less.  Most of
the time, a user defined copy constructor should start by copy 
constructing its bases:

```
C2::C2( C2 const& other )
    : C( other )
    , _i( other._i )
{
}
```

There are exceptions, however, and there are times when  you don't want
to copy the base.

Comment: Isn't it "the copy constructor for each base class, then the copy constructor for each member"? I was under the impression that base classes were initialized before members.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Yes.  There's a very strict order, in fact, which does first the virtual bases, in the order they are seen in a left to right depth first visit of the inheritance graph, then the non virtual bases, left to right as they appear in the class definition, then the members, again left to right.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the base class is called before the derived class, WHICH base class constructor is called however is up to the derived class specification.